# How can I use the same observable with multiple mappings?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-httpclient, subject-observer

My code has a `Subject` which, when new values are added triggers a HTTP request which returns an `Observable`.

I want to process this data in two different ways (using the same data) and use the resulting `Observables` stored in `group` and `times` as values to put in `ngFor` using the `async` pipe.

While this does work, the HTTP requests are sent multiple times - I only want them to be sent once for each subscription.

Below is a minimal example.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { Subject } from "rxjs/Subject";

import { ExampleService } from "../example.service";

import "rxjs/add/operator/switchMap";

@Component({
  templateUrl: "./example.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./example.component.scss"]
})
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private exampleService: ExampleService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    var selections = new Subject<string>();

    var appointments = selections
      // exampleService.getData returns an HTTP observable.
      .switchMap(date => this.exampleService.getData(date));

    var group = appointments
      .map(data => this.process(data));

    var times = appointments
      .map(data => this.calculateTimes(data));

    // Calling subscribe each time sends the HTTP request multiple
    // times - I only want it to be send once for both of them: they
    // can share the data!!
    group.subscribe();
    times.subscribe();

    // selections.next(someData) is called periodically from some
    // omitted code.
  }

  processExample(data: string[]) {
    /*
     * Some processing code.
    */

    return data;
  }

  calculateTimes(data: string[]) {
    /*
     * Some processing code.
    */

    return data;
  }
}
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `share` operator to archive what you are looking for:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/share';

ngOnInit() {

  var selections = new Subject<string>();

  var appointments = selections
    // exampleService.getData returns an HTTP observable.
    .switchMap(date => this.exampleService.getData(date))
    .share();

  var group = appointments
    .map(data => this.process(data));

  var times = appointments
    .map(data => this.calculateTimes(data));

  // Calling subscribe each time sends the HTTP request multiple
  // times - I only want it to be send once for both of them: they
  // can share the data!!
  group.subscribe();
  times.subscribe();

  // selections.next(someData) is called periodically from some
  // omitted code.
}
```

Basically, the different `observers` share the same `source` among them.

More info about the operator [here](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-share).